# Import database (Excel file) into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, import, excel

In order to import my database (excel file) into PostgreSQL, I converted the Excel file into ".csv" file. Then, I used the application: "Import Data For PostgreSQL" and  I could import my database but only the first 100 lines; knowing my database contains 80753 registration.

I tried  to import the database by SQL query, but an error message appear and I don't know how to solve it:

> ERREUR:  séquence d'octets invalide pour l'encodage « UTF8 » : 0xcce5.

Comment: There does not seem to be a GIS component to this question so I think our sister site [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to post it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Databases, and is a better fit for dba.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong encoding in your csv or postgresql, First check your default coding (probably UTF8) in postgresql then use [recode](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/index.html) to code file to needed encoding.

If you are using windows your exel/csv file is probably in win1251 or in your case (username uses strange charachters ) it could be also in Win 1256 (Arabic?)

see Also [SO - Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Comment: if asnwer solved your question, you should marks it answered, if not comment that it does not work could be good too :)

Comment: hi,the problem is solved in PostgreSQL, I create a table with the following query:

CREATE TABLE Migrant (fields ...)

then I exucutée the following query: client_encoding SET TO 'WIN1256';
to force the system to accept Arabic characters. and then I did the query:
Migrant COPY (fields ....)
  FROM 'C :/ base given / classeur.csv'
WITH DELIMITER as ';'
CSV HEADER

Comment: Interesting solution. Does that keep underlying table as utf8 encoding ?

Comment: yes, that keep underlying table as utf8 encoding